# How to display a "loading" animation while a lazy-loaded route component is being loaded?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-router

I have split my app into multiple chunks with webpack's code splitting feature so that the entire application bundle isn't downloaded when the user visits my webpage.

The chunks that some routes require can be reasonably large and may take a noticeable amount of time to download. This is fine, except the user is not aware that the page is actually loading when they click an internal link, so I need to somehow display a loading animation or something.

My router is configured like this:

```
[
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'landing' */ './landing.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/foo',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'main' */ './foo.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'main' */ './bar.vue'),
  },
]
```

[Advanced Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Advanced-Async-Components) in the Vue.js guide shows how to display a particular "loading" component while the component is being resolved -- this is exactly what I need, however it also says:

> Note that when used as a route component in vue-router, these properties will be ignored because async components are resolved upfront before the route navigation happens.

How can I achieve this in vue-router? If this is not possible, lazily-loaded components would be pretty much useless to me because it would provide a poor experience to the user.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use navigation guards to activate/deactivate a loading state that shows/hides a loading component:

If you would like to use something like "nprogress" you can do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xgrjzsup/2669/

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  NProgress.start()
  next()
})
router.afterEach(() => {
  NProgress.done()
})
```

Alternatively, if you want to show someting in-place:

http://jsfiddle.net/h4x8ebye/1/

```
Vue.component('loading',{ template: '<div>Loading!</div>'})

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  data: { loading: false },
  router
}).$mount('#app')

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  app.loading = true
    next()
})

router.afterEach(() => {
  setTimeout(() => app.loading = false, 1500) // timeout for demo purposes
})
```

Then in the template:

```
<loading v-if="$root.loading"></loading>
  <router-view v-else></router-view>
```

That could also be easily encapsulated in a very small component instead of using the `$root` component for the loading state.

Comment: It seems in the second example the next() function isn't defined; however, the process still runs and documentation shows it as a defined method in the vuejs router?

Comment: Hi Linus, are you able to elaborate on the following statement?
**"That could also be easily encasulated in a very small component instead of using the $root component for the loading state."**
Not really sure what you're referring to here

Comment: Using `beforeEach` doesn't help when deep-linking to some page (using someurl#/foo), as it doesn't get called initially. `beforeEnter` could be used, but has no access to 'app' initially. Do you have a solution to show a loading spinner when deep linking too?

Comment: You should probably open a new topic, I don't see how to discuss this in an answer's comments.

Comment: @linusborg created question on it's own for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49276470/176140

Comment: Don't know why but if you add a `$` prefix to the variable (i.e. `data: { $loading: false }`) the `app.$loading = true` has no effect in the view. Just beware.

Comment: From docs: `"You can also register global after hooks, however unlike guards, these hooks do not get a next function and cannot affect the navigation:"`, afterEach function doesn't get a next parameter, you should edit your answer.

Comment: @LinusBorg The router.afterEach does not get passed a next function, the provided script will error
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks

Answer (score 12):

For what it's worth, I'll share what I ended up doing for my situation.

I'm using Vuex so it was easy to create an app-wide "loading" state which any component can access, but you can use whatever mechanism you want to share this state.

Simplified, it works like this:

```js
function componentLoader(store, fn) {
  return () => {
    // (Vuex) Loading begins now
    store.commit('LOADING_BAR_TASK_BEGIN');

    // (Vuex) Call when loading is done
    const done = () => store.commit('LOADING_BAR_TASK_END');

    const promise = fn();
    promise.then(done, done);
    return promise;
  };
}

function createRoutes(store) {
  const load = fn => componentLoader(store, fn);

  return [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: load(() => import('./components/foo.vue')),
    },
    {
      path: '/bar',
      component: load(() => import('./components/bar.vue')),
    },
  ];
}
```

So all I have to do is wrap every `() => import()` by my `load()` function which takes care of setting the loading state. Loading is determined by observing the promise directly instead of relying on router-specific before/after hooks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for gobel route in one project of vuejs

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
      { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
      { path: '/about', name: 'about', component: About }
  ]
})

router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  // If this isn't an initial page load.
  if (to.name) {
      // Start the route progress bar.
      NProgress.start()
  }
  next()
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // Complete the animation of the route progress bar.
  NProgress.done()
})
```

Comment: `beforeResolve` is too late for this. `beforeResolve` is called after "Resolve async route components." so there is no point in showing progress then. You should call it in `beforeEach` for example.