# How to make Vue.js + Vuetify.js page elements to display only with CSS ready?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating a website with Vue.js + Vuetify.js

If I simulate "3G" in developer tools I can see all the elements of the **App.vue** page (toolbar, drawer,elements of routed pages) displaying without CSS during loading.

I preview it with webpack/localhost hot reload `npm run dev`

I want the spinner to load first and then the rest of the elements (with CSS). How do I do it properly?

I tried `v-cloak` and it isn't working. Looks like It's for hiding the `{{ }}`.

### project structure

#### index.html |

`<div id="app"></div>`

#### App.vue |

```
<v-app>
   <loader></loader>

   <div :v-show="false">
       ...
       <v-toolbar>...</v-toolbar>
       <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
</v-app>
```

these methods on the App.vue page doesn't seem to solve the problem:

```
 created: function () {show: true}
 mounted: function () {show: true}
```

P.S. I'm a newbie, so it's possible that I'm missing some small detail preventing it from working properly.

#### Question:

Could someone please show a proper way of doing it?

Comment: Create Vue instance in window.onload callback?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<v-app>
   <loader></loader>

   <div v-show="false">
       ...
       <v-toolbar>...</v-toolbar>
       <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
</v-app>
```

I think the v-show didn't work, bacause you use colon before, it's like passing a dynamic prop to the component instead of using v-show directive :)

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Still can't make it work though. Do you happen to know any tutorials out there that teach to handle loading in Vue ? A few google links didn't show anything worthwhile. All the elements are flickering on load. Not sure what's causing the problem

Comment: please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886812/how-to-display-a-loading-animation-while-a-lazy-loaded-route-component-is-bein

Comment: and this: https://medium.com/@jilsonthomas/vue-router-page-loading-effect-67290a3247a1